# How to order documents by a field content in firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of rooms for a hotel. When i add a new one or show the rooms list, they don't show from 1 to 5. Is there a way to order the rooms by their number?

[image: rooms list image]

The documents in room collection have their id generated automatically, and every room have a field called room number (ex : 1,2,3 ..)

```
final rooms = Provider.of<List<Room>>(context) ?? [];

return  StreamProvider<List<Room>>.value(
  initialData: [],
  value: DatabaseService().singleRoom,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Liste des chambre single"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      elevation: 2.0,
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/room_type_screen'),),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: Text(""),
          onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/admin_home'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          label: Text(""),
          onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add_room'),
        ),

      ],
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: rooms.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return RoomTile(room : rooms[index]);
      },
    ),
  ),
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
void deleteRoomFromDatabase(String id){
  final CollectionReference singleRoomCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rooms/single/room");
  singleRoomCollection.doc(id).delete();
}
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child: Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
      child: GridTileBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          // backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/6074.jpg'),
          child: Text("${room.numChambre.toString().substring(1)}",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: room.reserver?Text("Chambre réservé"):Text('Chambre disponible',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
        subtitle: Text("Prix : "+room.prix.toString()),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          onPressed: (){
            deleteRoomFromDatabase(room.roomId);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to order your result from:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rooms/single/room")
```

use the .orderBy() function.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rooms/single/room").orderBy("FieldInFirestoreToOrderBy", descending: true/false)
```

If you wanna filter the result you can also use the .where function

Comment: Good answer. As far as I can tell from reading the question, the field to order on is `numChambre`.